# How do i properly format JSON in Html code

Tags: html, json

I am new at Html coding and my goal here is to send a measurement (pH in this case) upon clicking a button.  I keep getting the error, failed to parse JSON string.  I am fairly sure it has something to do with the var ItemJSON and how I have it represented.  Have tried different approaches but was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. thanks in advance.

```
   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function send()
{

    var ItemJSON;

    ItemJSON = '[  {"c8y_ph":{"ph":{"value":11,"unit":"na"}},"time":"2020-06-30T12:46:14.000+02:00","source":{"id":"681700"},"type":"c8y_ph"} ]';

    URL = "https://myurl.com/measurement/measurements" ;  //Your URL

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.open("POST", URL, false);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa('username:pw')); //in prod, you should encrypt user name and password and provide encrypted keys here instead 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callbackFunction(xmlhttp);
    xmlhttp.send(ItemJSON);
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = xmlhttp.statusText + ":" + xmlhttp.status + "<BR><textarea rows='100' cols='100'>" + xmlhttp.responseText + "</textarea>";
}

function callbackFunction(xmlhttp) 
{
    //alert(xmlhttp.responseXML);
}
</script>


<html>
<body id='bod'><button type="submit" onclick="javascript:send()">call</button>
<div id='div'>

</div></body>
</html>
```

Comment: The JSON string you pasted is valid and no need to format it. And what is the error you're getting? maybe it's a server error.

Comment: Bad request - error 400.  Failed to parse JSON string.  I have initiated this call from Postman and the measurement was posted so the problem is not the api call per say, but could be the HTMLwidget I'm trying to use?

Comment: You'll probably need to look at the server logs, because the JSON looks fine. Also, maybe the JSON is a bit different between here and Postman.